# How can i achieve row group in SlickGride?

Tags: slickgrid, angular-slickgrid

How can I achieve the **row grouping** in Angular Slickgrid API?

I need this type of row group

[image]

Comment: You can do dynamic height in SlickGrid so you can't do directly what you're showing in your print screen. You can however look at some other features like Grouping, Row Detail or Tree Data